# how to sync the rendertarget between two dx9 process?

Tags: c++, directx, game-engine, directx-9

one process is consumer, one process is producer.
1.create 3 rt in producer process, send handle to consumer process.
2.open 3 rt use the handle in cousumer process.
3.set rt, render, and issue a TIMESTAMPDISJOINT query in consumer process, i don't call present().
4.at third frame i call query->GetData(flag = 0), but the render is still not end.
if i call present(), getData() can return, but the fps is very low.

is there some sample of share a rt between two dx9 process?
Thanks.

Comment: Multiprocess dx rendering for game engine? Are you sure you don't mean multithreaded?

Comment: yes, editor is a process, game render is a process.